# Spices and candles before your zman

Tags: halacha, shabbat, zemanim, havdalah

If one holds 72 minutes for shabbas to be over and they are staying by someone who holds 50 minutes and they make havdalla by 50 min can the 72-minute-people participate in their havdalla to fulfill the "obligations" of besamim and getting hanah from the fire? I am not asking about fulfilling the actual havdalla part.

Sources please.

Comment: You can make Havdalla from plag hamincha....

Comment: I know the Rambam,my question is the participation of the besamim and aish

Comment: It's also Shulchan Arukh and all achronim...

Comment: I know that's talking about in teffilah ,but not the rabbinic al hakos

Comment: ??? Did I misunderstand you in my editing? You can say Havdalla on a Kos from Plag HaMincha. This is undisputed to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Is this question referring to one who holds shabbos doesn't end of the ר"ת time or just is machmir on himself?

Comment: Offhand, if a person follows Shabbat by R. Tam's time, wouldn't the besamim and fire be muktzah for him?

Comment: @DanF Why would Besamim be Muktza?

Comment: Yes, only the fire. I guess I was questioing the idea of the besamim box that is specifically reserved for havdalah, as it's not meant for Shabbat use since it's designated for havdalah?